# How to add Areas in Orchard CMS Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have OPAC Search website developed using MVC4. It has number of MVC Areas. This time I need to implement or integrate with Orchard CMS. I have a question How can I use those same  MVC Areas in Orchard Module and If it can be done How can be the Routing for those Areas.

Any suggestion to this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Orchard modules are implemented as MVC areas, so I guess you should migrate each area as a separate Orchard module.

You can define custom routing for each module by implementing the `IRouteProvider` interface. For example, the following code maps an action `MyAction` in controller `MyController` to the URL `Foo/Bar`. Of course you must replace `MyModule` with the name of your Orchard module.

```
public class Routes : IRouteProvider
{
    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
    {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in this.GetRoutes())
        {
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] 
                  {
                       new RouteDescriptor
                       {
                           Priority = 20,
                           Route =
                               new Route(
                               "Foo/Bar",
                               new RouteValueDictionary
                               {
                                   { "area", "MyModule" },
                                   { "controller", "MyController" },
                                   { "action", "MyAction" }
                               },
                               new RouteValueDictionary(),
                               new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "MyModule" } },
                               new MvcRouteHandler())
                       },
                       // Other routes...
                   };
    }
}
```